# How to handle multiple checked items and display them on a loop one by one in a msgbox

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

I want to get all the checked items from a `CheckedListBox` and add each item to a variable such as item1, item2, etc.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim item1 As String
    Dim item2 As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
        If i = 1 Then
            item1 = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(i)
            MsgBox(item1)
        ElseIf i > 1 Then
            item1 = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(i)
            item2 = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(i)
            MsgBox(item1 + item2)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

How can I show all the selected items in a `MsgBox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the issue is just that you're not sure how to handle multiple checked items, just use a StringBuilder and not individual variables.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

    For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
        sb.AppendLine(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(i))
    Next

    MsgBox(sb.ToString())

End Sub
```

As a side note, don't use + for concatenating strings, use the & operator.

Comment: how would i assign item 2 then? lets say if the cheked items name was "test1" and checked item 2 was "test2" and checked item 3 was "test3" how would i add them all to an individual variable?

Comment: and what am i supposed to do with msgbox(item1) its not being used anywhere?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the MsgBox.  See my edit.  Do you need the individual variables for some reason?

Comment: i have a question lets say i wanted to check all the checklistboxitems from that i insert to a access database. how would i be able to do that?

Comment: @JTUP - That should be posted as a separate question.  In general, you would create OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand objects to send a query to Access for each checked item.